# mongodb 4.1 full join between 2 collections

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongo 4.1, I have 2 collections with matching cols a,b,c. How can I do a full join to get all cols between the 2 ?

```
TabA  
colA,colB,colC,colD,colE
```

```
TabB
colA,colB,colC,colF,colG,colH
```

```
Desired Result:
colA,colB,colC,colD,colE,colF,colG,colH
```

It is possible for the same data to exist in both `TabA` and `TabB`, but there will be cases where data is in `TabA` and not in `TabB` and vice-versa. Nulls would be expected in `colsD/E/F/G/H` in that case.
I know mongodb is not relational, but someone must've overcome this....
been toying with exported csv joins in Excel out of desperation but i don't want to go that route
Thanks for any advice..

Comment: check out $unionWith - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/

Comment: Thanks, looks promising but it's new in 4.4 , i'm still in 4.1

Comment: I don't know if you can use `lookup` and `mergeObjects`. If so, you could do something like this. https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZnZYwnCcKv7